# Changing Semicolon from Multi-Select Picklist values to a Comma

Tags: formula, formula-field, multi-select

I am having difficulty creating a formula that would remove the semicolon from Salesforce Multi-Select picklist values to a comma.

Basically I want "A;B;C" to appear as "A,B,C"

I tried using a formula below but it did not work out as I intended:

`IF(INCLUDES(myMultiSelectPicklistfield_c, ";"), "," ,   "")`

Any suggestions are really appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can [only use the following functions with Multi-Select Picklist fields](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm):

> - [INCLUDES](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#INCLUDES)
> - [ISBLANK](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISBLANK)
> - [ISNULL](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISNULL)
> - [ISCHANGED](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISCHANGED) (Only in assignment rules, validation rules, workflow field updates, and workflow rules in which the evaluation criteria is set to Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited )
> - [PRIORVALUE](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#PRIORVALUE) (Only in assignment rules, validation rules, workflow field updates, and workflow rules in which the evaluation criteria is set to Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited )

None of these really work for substitution, unless you want to pursue a really ugly concatenation scheme using `IF(INCLUDES(Multiselect__c), "a,", "") & IF(INCLUDES(...), "...", "")`. In addition to being ugly, this formula would likely exceed character limits, and you have to deal with the trailing comma somehow.

However, it would be fairly straightforward in a `before` trigger.

```
for (MyObject__c record : trigger.new)
{
    if (record.Multiselect__c != null)
    {
        record.SecondField__c = record.Multiselect__c.replace(';', ',');
    }
}
```

You should question what you are really trying to achieve with this secondary field. There may be alternative, simpler means.

If you pursue an `Apex Trigger`, you should read up carefully on [Trigger Frameworks and Apex Trigger Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices).

Comment: Is there any way to replace the semicolon by comma in the multiselect picklist field itself rather than other field?

Comment: No there is not.