# a copy of Changing Semicolon from Multi-Select Picklist values to a Comma

Tags: formula-field

It is an exact copy of existing [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143778/changing-semicolon-from-multi-select-picklist-values-to-a-comma). I need answer for this issue in formula field only. 
I found a small solution to it and given below.

```
IF( INCLUDES( Mul_Pick__c , "One"), "One" +',' , NULL) + 
IF(INCLUDES( Mul_Pick__c  , "Two"), "Two" +',' , NULL) + 
IF(INCLUDES( Mul_Pick__c , "three"), "Three" +',' , NULL) + 
IF(INCLUDES( Mul_Pick__c  , "four"), "four"  , NULL)
```

If we select all pick list fields, then only I can get exact output like `one, two, three, four`. If I select other than all fields, it will show like `one,` or `two,` or `one, two,` or `one, three, two,` and etc. But, what ever the fields I selected, the result should not be come comma at end of the fields.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use two more formulas to achieve desired result: `LEFT`, `LEN`

```
LEFT(
    IF(INCLUDES(Mul_Pick__c, "One"), "One" +',' , NULL) + 
    IF(INCLUDES(Mul_Pick__c, "Two"), "Two" +',' , NULL) + 
    IF(INCLUDES(Mul_Pick__c, "three"), "Three" +',' , NULL) + 
    IF(INCLUDES(Mul_Pick__c, "four"), "four"  +',', NULL),
    (LEN(
        IF(INCLUDES(Mul_Pick__c, "One"), "One" +',' , NULL) + 
        IF(INCLUDES(Mul_Pick__c, "Two"), "Two" +',' , NULL) + 
        IF(INCLUDES(Mul_Pick__c, "three"), "Three" +',' , NULL) + 
        IF(INCLUDES(Mul_Pick__c, "four"), "four"  +',', NULL)
        ) - 1)
)
```

Comment: HI @Alexander Berehovskiy, Thank you for you share. Its working now

Comment: Alexander Berehovskiy, I got one more issue, could you please help in this?

Comment: @KSKumaar yes, is it related to the same formula?

Comment: Yes. It is. Basically, I need to add a word between the last two words like `One,Two,Three or Four` and `One,Two or Four` and `One or Four` and `three, four or two` .

Comment: Have you tried it. I tried for it. But result comes with failure always.